# dotnet publish multiple output files with the same relative path - but its the same file from the same project?

Tags: c#, .net, build

When using `dotnet publish` I keep getting "error `NETSDK1152`: Found multiple publish output files with the same relative path".

However, the files listed in the error message are the same file - once in the project folder (alongside the .cs files) and once in the output folder. The files are set to be copied to the output folder in the csproj, so them showing up in the output folder is correct - I just don't know why `dotnet publish` tries to copy them from the source folder as well?

```
error NETSDK1152: Es wurden mehrere Ausgabedateien für die Veröffentlichung mit demselben relativen Pfad gefunden: 
D:\Dev\Repo\project\3rdPartyDll.dll, 
D:\Dev\Repo\project\bin\Debug\net7.0-windows\win-x64\3rdPartyDll.dll
D:\Dev\Repo\project\3rdPartyDll.xml 
D:\Dev\Repo\project\bin\Debug\net7.0-windows\win-x64\3rdPartyDll.xml
```

To make it even more strange, those are not the only files in this project set to be copied to the output folder. The csproj looks like this:

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Update="Different3rdPartyDll.dll">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
    <None Update="3rdPartyDll.dll">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
    <None Update="3rdPartyDll.xml">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
    <None Update="AnotherDifferentDll.dll">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
    <None Update="AnotherDifferentDll.xml">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
    <None Update="YetAnpotherOne.dll">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
  </ItemGroup>
```

But the other files are not listed in the error message.

I am really confused here. I also searched the whole repository after a clean clone - the only occurence of the file(s) is `D:\Dev\Repo\project\3rdPartyDll.dll|xml`.